# Creating multiple RDP sessions from HTML document

Tags: remote-desktop, regex, automation, html, rdc-manager

There is a website that lists data about hundreds of computers on our network in a table. This includes their IPs. I will routinely need to connect to these computers to do some troubleshooting, so I was thinking of making the task easier for myself so that I don't have to enter the IP and credentials into RDP every time (I use the same creds for all of them).

I don't have direct access to this data though, so I was thinking of extracting it using a regex on the HTML document of the website. The entries in the table look something like this (in HTML):

```
    <td>Computer 1</td> <!-- Name needed to identify the computer -->
    <td>...</td> <!-- Misc data -->
    <td>...</td> <!-- Misc data -->
    <td>...</td> <!-- Misc data -->
    <td>a.b.c.d</td> <!-- IP address -->
    <td>...</td> <!-- Misc data -->
    <td>...</td> <!-- Misc data -->
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, or if this is the best approach. My ultimate goal is to have access to these remote desktops with a simple click. I have RDCMan set up but I don't want to go through each computer and add it manually.

Comment: Would you be ok with installing powershell? I could write a script to grab all the connections for you, it will make a connection list of bat files

Comment: I'm using Win10, PS is already installed

Comment: In this list of commands, which one would you like? https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Connect-Mstsc-Open-RDP-2064b10b

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239). HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.